# Python regex for finding all words in a string

Tags: python, regex, words, sentence

Hello I am new into regex and I'm starting out with python.
I'm stuck at extracting all words from an English sentence.
So far I have:

```
import re

shop="hello seattle what have you got"
regex = r'(\w*) '
list1=re.findall(regex,shop)
print list1
```

This gives output:

> ['hello', 'seattle', 'what', 'have', 'you']

If I replace regex by

```
regex = r'(\w*)\W*'
```

then output:

> ['hello', 'seattle', 'what', 'have', 'you', 'got', '']

whereas I want this output

> ['hello', 'seattle', 'what', 'have', 'you', 'got']

Please point me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 21):

Use word boundary `\b`

```
import re

shop="hello seattle what have you got"
regex = r'\b\w+\b'
list1=re.findall(regex,shop)
print list1

OP : ['hello', 'seattle', 'what', 'have', 'you', 'got']
```

or simply `\w+` is enough

```
import re

shop="hello seattle what have you got"
regex = r'\w+'
list1=re.findall(regex,shop)
print list1

OP : ['hello', 'seattle', 'what', 'have', 'you', 'got']
```