# How to find a link in a big string

Tags: python, python-3.x, find

I want to find a link like `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543724/python-regex-for-finding-all-words-in-a-string`

in a big string but there are many links and I want all links that starts with `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/` the string look like

something `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543724/python-regex-for-finding-all-words-in-a-string` something

So my question is how can i find an uncompletet string?

Comment: Hello! Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What specific problem are you encountering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import re
  
def Find(string):
  
    # findall() has been used 
    # with valid conditions for urls in string
    regex = r"(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))"
    url = re.findall(regex,string)      
    return [x[0] for x in url if "stackoverflow.com/questions" in x[0]]
      
# Driver Code
string = 'content_license CC BY-SA 4.0 link https//stackoverflow.com/questions/26325943/many-threads-to-write-log-file-at-same-time-in-python title Many threads to writ'
print(Find(string))
```

This outputs: `['stackoverflow.com/questions/26325943/many-threads-to-write-log-file-at-same-time-in-python']`, which is what I assume you want.

Comment: Yes this worked but in the string are many links can i configure in regex?

Comment: What do you mean? This program does gets multiple links from a string.

Comment: Yes but there are many link that i don't want to have i only want the links that start with stackoverflow.com/questions/

Comment: See the edit above. I changed the `return` statement to `return [x[0] for x in url if "stackoverflow.com/questions" in x[0]]`. Basically, this only adds an element to the list if the url contains `stackoverflow.com/questions`.